# Angular CDK Drag and Drop: Cancel drag-action

Tags: angular, drag, angular2-directives, angular-cdk

With the new drag and drop feature of the @angular/cdk (I'm currently using version 7.0.0-beta.2), is it possible to cancel a drag-action?

I did not find a matching function on 'CdkDrag' which could do the trick.

**Edit from 2019-01-10**

Thanks for the responses so far. I guess I wasn't clear enough, though: I'm looking for a way to cancel a drag-action which is already in progress. I. e. while dragging an item, I want to have the possibility to make that item return to the container where it comes from (e. g. by pressing the Escape key).

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm looking to find out as well!

Comment: Sadly it doesn't yet look like there's an API do do this: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13661

Answer (score 6):

it's not possible with anguar 7.0.0, you have to update to angular 7.1.0, then you have:

```
[cdkDragDisabled]="condition"
```

which works perfect!

Comment: Can I show moving the same card as it through CSS. As in the image (link) it is showing moving text data not the whole card (with CSS styles)  https://medium.com/@er.markar/can-i-show-moving-the-same-card-as-it-through-css-9edda248094

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable dragging for a particular drag item, you can do so by setting the cdkDragDisabled input on a cdkDrag item.

```
<div cdkDropList class="list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
<div *ngFor="let item of dragedItems" cdkDrag 
[cdkDragDisabled]="item.disabled"> {{item.value}} </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A reset function has recently been added to CdkDrag.

As example, if you have the following draggable div:

```
<div cdkDrag (cdkDragEnded)="onDragEnded($event)"></div>
```

You can restore it to its original position like this:

```
onDragEnded(event: CdkDragEnd): void {
    if (condition) {
        event.source._dragRef.reset();
    }
}
```

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13661

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for that feature for ages. Turns out, it is simple enough:

```
private _canceledByEsc = false;

@HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.key === 'Escape') {
        this._canceledByEsc = true;
        document.dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseup'));
    }
}

handleDrop() {
    if (!this._canceledByEsc) {
        // probably just return and don't do any array manipulations
    }
}
```

(seen on [Cancel drag on key press Angular cdk Drag and Drop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53609182/8661349))